# How do you use variables with values containing spaces in a Z-shell (zsh) script command?

Tags: shell-script, zsh

I have the following Z-shell script:

```
compiler=clang++
standard=-std=c++11
warnings="-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic"
${compiler} ${warnings} ${standard} -o ${1} ${1}.cpp
```

This does not work as the ${warnings} variable appears to be seen as 
"-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic" - that is one long warning with spaces, versus three separate warnings.

I did some searching and was able to get it to work with eval:

```
eval "${compiler} ${warnings} ${standard} -o ${1} ${1}.cpp"
```

However, I am confused as to why it is necessary, and also is there some other way to correct this issue.

EDIT: In addition to doing it as shown in Peter O. 's answer, I found that you can do:

```
setopt shwordsplit
```

to get the Z-shell to behave like other Bourne shell derivatives. As they [say in their FAQ](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq03.html#l17):

> In most Bourne-shell derivatives, multiple-word variables such as
>
> ```
> var="foo bar"
> ```
>
> are split into words when passed to a command or used in a for foo in
>   $var loop. By default, zsh does not have that behaviour: the variable
>   remains intact. (This is not a bug! See below.) The option
>   SH_WORD_SPLIT exists to provide compatibility.

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: @Gilles I was using the z-shell. I just checked and the problem does not exist when run with bash.

Comment: Answers do not go in questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set your Warning options as an array. `"${warnings[@]}"` generates 3 individual *words*

```
warnings=(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)

"${compiler}" "${warnings[@]}" "${standard}" -o "${1}" "${1}.cpp"
```

---

Or, if you find it more legible, you can create the array without `-W`'s, and then add `-W`'s via how you present the array on the command line.

```
warnings=( all extra pedantic )

"${compiler}" "${warnings[@]/#/-W}" "${standard}" -o "${1}" "${1}.cpp"
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess you figured out I was using the Z-shell. I just found out that it worked the string way with bash (tried in  response to question above).

Comment: Why doesn't putting quotes around ${warnings[@]/#/w} recreate the problem - that is a string with spaces getting passed to the shell?

Comment: It seems that I can just do ${warnings} and the array gets expanded into 3 separate strings and the command works.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `$=` to split a variable by `$IFS`:

```
${compiler} ${=warnings} ${standard} -o ${1} ${1}.cpp
```